# Search query and count results many to many relationships in laravel

Tags: laravel, search, relationship

I'm using the plugin TokenInput to perform search tag.
I have 2 tables with many to many relationship. Table: Story, Tag and pivot table: story_tag. I execute a search query:

```
$term = request('q');
$tags = \App\Tag::where('slug', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')->get();

return response()->json($tags->toArray());
```

It's working. Now, I want to count the number of tags in the pivot table story_tag and display the result as like:

tagNamea - 69

tagNameb - 9

...

I tried many searches, but did not have the desired result. How to do it? Any help? Thanks.

**Update:**

Relationship model:

Story model:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
}
```

Tag model:

```
public function stories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Story');
}
```

Comment: what  is this **tagNamea**?

Comment: It is the result of the query from the Tag table. Number 69 is count number in the pivot table. It corresponds to the number of occurrences of a tag in the pivot table.

Comment: Can you please let us know how you have defined the relationship between Story and Tag in model?

Comment: I've updated above.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have relationship like this

```
public function stories()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Story', 'story_tag', 'tag_id', 'story_id');
}
```

i dont know what response you need but relationship you have to mention like above

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have an eloquent collection you can use **count** method on that collection.

For example:

```
$count = $tags->count();
```

Here if your **$tags** is a collection then you will get the number of tags in **$count**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$tags->count()`. **count()** method will count all the results of the collection.